# Where to specify --module flag in VS 2015?

Tags: asp.net, typescript

I am using typescript 1.5 and VS 2015 RC with new ASP.NET 5 Project templates. 
Typescript compiles fine however I am getting the following error on my exported classes:

> cannot compile external modules unless the "-module" flag is provided

I want to silence this error however I am unable to specify any typescript options though VS 2015. I also tried `tsconfig.json` file however it seems it is not effective to just  add this file. Perhaps there is an additional step I am missing. What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this setting is in the project properties on the TypeScript build tab in the project properties (for your current build configuration such as Debug or Release).

Since you are saying that the TypeScript build tab doesn't appear, you may not have a valid reference to the TypeScript "props" file in your project.  Look for a line like this in your `.csproj` or similar file:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />`

If it doesn't exist, add it to your project and then fix up the path to be correct for your install of Visual Studio and TypeScript (just search for the "Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" file on your hard drive).  When you reload the project, the TypeScript build properties tab should appear.

The other thing you need is a reference to the TypeScript "targets" file such as this:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />`

Note that a targets reference generally has to be as low as possible in your project - possibly even just before the `</Project>` tag.

Initialization of TypeScript in Visual Studio is dependent on the .props and .targets files existing so that could also be the issue.

Comment: Waw, you saved my day! in VS2015 the Typescript Build tab is indeed sometimes invisible. Adding the import....default.props line in the .csproj file fixed this!